# Android wave animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, material-design, android-transitions

I found very very beautiful transition animation, and now i want to implement this animation to my application.

Here is [example](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/14268/screenshots/1708213/finder.gif).

I found only one library that provide something  like that, it is [here](http://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1918).  But it shows only enter animation and does not provide exit animation. And animation is not smooth.
Maybe someone was doing something like this and can help me?

Answer (score 2):

The animation you described is called circular reveal. Works only on Lollipop and Marshmallow. If this is your target, just google a tutorial about circular reveal animation and implement it.

If you want to have it on older devices, you have two options:

**Transit to a single color and then fade other views in.**
This one is very simple and performant. You can just draw a circle with scale animation. It can be hardware accelerated and is very easy to implement.

- Extend a view
- Make id draw a circle in its onDraw method
- Position it correctly over the starting point
- Add a scale animation and an animation listener
- Do something with your second child in onAnimationEnd

**Make a transition between two complete views**
This one is more interesting. It's called masking or masked transition. Take a look at TransitionLayout from [Carbon](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon). These two methods are particulary important:

[void startRadialTransition(int duration)](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/blob/master/carbon/src/main/java/carbon/beta/TransitionLayout.java#L115)

[void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/blob/master/carbon/src/main/java/carbon/beta/TransitionLayout.java#L157)

Basically you have to:

- Draw one child to a layer
- Draw the second child to a separate layer
- Mask that layer with a circle
- Merge these two layers and draw them on the view's canvas
- Increase circle's radius and repeat

Comment: I want add this animation to activity transition. Thx for answer, i will try.